# Any active missions besides the introductory ones?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I've played over 30 hours in 7 Days to Die now thanks to my group of friends carrying me.  Having completed the initial set of missions, from crafting your own stone axe till visiting the trader, is there anything else available for completion?

I remember hearing my friend saying he has some sort of challenge which requires him to kill 5 bears or 10 dogs. I dont have any of these active challenges though. Are there any ways I can invoke them to keep my 7 Days to Die experience interesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenges your friend speaks of need to be found first.  They look like yellow post-it notes in your inventory/in containers/in zombies as loot.  They aren't very common to come across however.

Here are some ways that I've found them:

- Looting dead zombies
- Searching bookcases (one of the better methods I've found)
- Searching filing cabinets

These are just a few ways. Since its random, I would say anything could contain them. I've always found that bookcases contain them more often than other containers.

Once you find one, read it like you would a book or schematic, and it will prompt you with what the challenge is and if you want to accept it or not (if you decline it, you will still retain the challenge so that you can read it again when you are ready).  Some challenges I've come across include finding buried treasure, killing specific zombies, and killing certain animals.

For a list of the quests/challenges, check out the [7 days to die DB](https://www.7daysdb.com/quests).

Comment: Keep in mind that both the quests you refer to, and the challenges, are relatively new additions to the game, so expect more to be added, over time.